# Code gets skipped after doing a HttpRequest

Tags: c#, http, xamarin, android-recyclerview, webapi

So I'm making a POST call to my API to get multiple objects which then get added to a list and are displayed in the RecyclerView. The problem is, after getting to the **var result** it skips the entire remaining code in that method and executes the next method **SetupRecyclerView**. The catch doesn't catch any exception. What's wrong with that code?

```
async void GetPostList()
        {
            try
            {
                string url = "linkToMyWebService";
                var uri = new Uri(url);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    RequestUri = uri
                };

                HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
                var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var contentBody = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                List<postRetrieved> posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<postRetrieved>>(contentBody);
                foreach (var post in posts)
                {
                    postModel newPost = new postModel();
                    newPost.username = post.fullName;
                    newPost.description = post.postTitle;
                    newPost.city = post.postCity;
                    postList.Add(newPost);
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

        }


        void SetupRecyclerView()
        {
            postRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new Android.Support.V7.Widget.LinearLayoutManager(postRecyclerView.Context));
            postAdapter = new PostAdapter(MainScreenPosts);
            postRecyclerView.SetAdapter(postAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: Your empty catch block will make it really hard to know when your code is throwing an error.  At a *minimum*, **log the error**.  If you aren't going to handle the exception, don't silently catch it and throw the error away like that.  It only makes it harder to debug your code.

Comment: That is probably what is happening.  Your code is likely throwing an exception, which is getting silently thrown away.  Execution would resume after the close of the `catch` block.  Without specific information about the exception, we can't diagnose it further than that.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely about Catch. Some error is being returned, and an empty catch causes the method to get skipped.
You can either enable "Common Language Runtime Exception" in "Exception settings" or log the error inside the catch. This will help you to get more details about what went wrong in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, so the problem was with the fact that GetPostList was asynchronous. While waiting for the request to get the list of objects, it started doing the method SetupRecyclerView which required those objects to function. I've put that in the Finally{} block in my trycatch and now it works fine.